# How to retrieve child object data from dynamic Sooql Query resultset?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I need to fetch the name of objects from custom setting and based on the name I need to create a dynamic Sooql for getting child objects id in order to share them with specific users.

Please see below part of trigger code that I am trying in order to achieve this.

```
SubQ =',(select id from ' + CustomMap.get(objName).API_Field__c + ')'; 
String queryStr=' select id '+ SubQuery + ' from Account where id in:accId';

List<Account> objdata =Database.query(queryStr);

for(String objName : CustomMap.keyset()) {

// Here custom map contains object name as key.
// objdata is the Account List created from sooql.

     for(Account ac : objdata){
       for(objName obj : ac.objName ){

      if(recordIdsMap.containsKey('ObjName')){
          List<String> recordIds = recordIdsMap.get('ObjName');
            recordIds.add(obj.Id);
            system.debug('recordIds' + recordIds);
           recordIdsMap.put('ObjName',recordIds);
           }
            else{
             system.debug('Recordid'  + obj.id);

            recordIdsMap.put('ObjName', new List<String> {obj.id});

}
```

but its giving typecasting errors here at line:

```
for(objName obj : ac.objName ){
```

because objname is string and not object here and even if I try to convert it to sobject it won't work because soject id supermost object and won't be able to call it from account.

If I hardcode the object here like so:

```
 for(cases obj : ac.cases){
```

it will work but my requirement is to make it generic.

Comment: Please do not beg for special attention here ("help me", "urgent", "asap" etc) - no questions are more important than others here, and adding this noise just creates editing work. Thanks.